# How can I calculate the average of 1 variable of Array of Custom Type

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, multidimensional-array

This is a tricky one for me to explain, so I'll start with the code I have so far, and later with what I am trying to achieve.

**Current Code**

```
Option Explicit

Public eSigTickerArr As Variant

' Public type to save array
Type Watchlist
    eSigTicker As String
    Op As Double
    Hi As Double
    Lo As Double
    Cl As Double
    Vol As Double
    BarTime As Variant
End Type
Public WatchlistArr() As Watchlist ' save an array of special type "Watchlist"

'====================================================================

Sub Mainr()

ReDim WatchlistArr(0) ' init array size
eSigTickerArr = Array("Part1", "Part2", "Part3") 

For Each eSigTickerElem In eSigTickerArr

    ' check if first member of array is occupied
    If WatchlistArr(0).eSigTicker <> "" Then ' not first time running this code >> increase array size by 1
        ReDim Preserve WatchlistArr(UBound(WatchlistArr) + 1) ' increase array size by 1
    End If

    ' ... Some Code, working fine ....

    ' populate array Type with data (also works)
    With WatchlistArr(UBound(WatchlistArr))
        .eSigTicker = eSigTickerElem
        .Op = LastCSVLine(2)
        .Hi = LastCSVLine(3)
        .Lo = LastCSVLine(4)
        .Cl = LastCSVLine(5)
        .Vol = LastCSVLine(6)
        .BarTime = LastCSVLine(1)
    End With

Next eSigTickerElem

' ******* calculate the average of only "Hi"  ******
Dim myAvg

myAvg = WorksheetFunction.Average(WatchlistArr.Hi) '<--- Getting an Error !

End Sub
```

I'm getting an error at the line above.

**My Challenge**: I want to get the average only of a certain variable of my type array `WatchlistArr`, and I don't want to use a loop, as there can be 10,000 records (or more).

Is there any way to get the value with the `Average` function ?

Should I switch to 2-D array ? or Maybe 3-D array ?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a loop?  They are very fast, even with tens of thousands of iterations.

Comment: How is `Average` possibly implemented? Oh, that's right! A loop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myAvg = WorksheetFunction.Average(WatchlistArr.Hi) '<--- Getting an Error !
```

Yep. What this code *means* to do is similar to this:

```
myAvg = watchListArr.Select(item => item.Hi).Average();
```

Where `item => item.Hi` is a selector function that is invoked **for every item** in `watchListArr`. The only problem is that this is LINQ / C#, not VBA. VBA doesn't support delegates and other funky stuff even C# couldn't dream to do in v1.0.

But VBA *has* control flow structures that let you perform an action *for every item* in an array: use a `For` loop!

```
Dim i As Long, total As Double, count As Long
For i = LBound(watchListArr) To UBound(watchListArr)
    total = total + watchListArr(i).Hi
    If watchListArr(i).Hi <> 0 Then count = count + 1 'assuming zeroes are excluded
Next i
If count <> 0 Then myAvg = total / count
```

If you want to use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Average`, you'll need to copy the `Hi` member of every item in your array into its own array, and give it *that* array - and that will require... a loop... which is wasted cycles if that loop isn't *also* computing the average as it goes.

As long as you're not using a `For Each` loop to iterate the array, you'll do fine. Iterating a 30K items array with a `For` loop is pretty much instant, no worries there.

Comment: Thanks, how much time it takes to loop through ~30,000 records ? I'm debating if to switch to a 2D array? I might even have to go for 3D array in order to escape the loop. My question is it worth it ?

Comment: @ShaiRado well I just wrote a quick test with one iteration to populate 30K items and another to compute the sum of one element of the UDT in each of the 30K items, and the two loops completed instantly. I wouldn't worry about performance until performance is an actual problem. Ever heard the phrase "premature optimization"? BTW `WorksheetFunction.Average` is **NOT** eliminating the loop, it just abstracts it away from *your* code.

Comment: you're still number 1!

Comment: @ShaiRado nope, [you are ;-)](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vba/topusers)

Answer (score 1):

You could define `WatchlistArr` as a 2-D array and then try this logic:

```
Dim myArray As Variant
myArray = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(WatchlistArr, 0, 2)
```

This will return column 2 as as array, which can be passed into the Average method:

```
myAvg = WorksheetFunction.Average(myArray)
```